# Make some tick labels larger than others in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

Is there a way to make only certain tick labels for a plot in matplotlib bold, or bigger than the other? For example, I have a list of x tick labels that are device names, and I want to make the most popular ones be bold or larger than the less used devices, anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic example would be like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,4.5,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks([1,2,3], ['this', 'is', 'custom'])

font_sizes = [10,20,30]

for tick, size in zip(plt.xticks()[-1], font_sizes):
    tick.set_fontsize(size)
```

As far as I know, you have to do them individually, as opposed to supplying a list somewhere..

[image: plot]

Comment: FYI - `'set_font_properties', 'set_fontname', 'set_fontproperties', 'set_fontsize', 'set_fontstretch', 'set_fontstyle', 'set_fontvariant', 'set_fontweight'`, there's also all of those to change as well